# Apache fails to load when SSL activated through Pacemaker

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost, pacemaker

I have setup a cluster on Pacemaker holding: apache, mariadb, 2x GFS2, and a VIP

Everything was working fine when running on `http` but as soon as I added the (self-signed) SSL certificate and the virtual host to `httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file, the cluster won't start the web server again.

I have searched for results on the `/server-status` and SSL/https but I cant fund any results on how to conjure it.

When I run:

```
[root@node01 ~]# pcs resource debug-start mb-web
Operation start for mb-web (ocf:heartbeat:apache) returned: 'unknown error' (1)
> stderr: May 18 12:38:43 INFO: apache not running
> stderr: May 18 12:38:43 INFO: waiting for apache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up
> stderr: ocf-exit-reason:Failed to access httpd status page.
> stderr: May 18 12:38:44 INFO: Attempting graceful stop of apache PID 31950
> stderr: May 18 12:38:46 INFO: apache stopped.
```

I also get it in the failed messages:

```
Failed Resource Actions:
* mb-web_start_0 on node01 'unknown error' (1): call=128, status=complete, exitreason='Failed to access httpd status page.',
last-rc-change='Mon May 18 12:32:05 2020', queued=0ms, exec=3402ms
* mb-web_start_0 on node02 'unknown error' (1): call=130, status=complete, exitreason='Failed to access httpd status page.',
last-rc-change='Mon May 18 12:31:35 2020', queued=0ms, exec=3425ms
```

I have tried updating the resource via:

```
pcs resource update mb-web statusurl="https://localhost/server-status"
or
pcs resource update mb-web statusurl="https://127.0.0.1/server-status"
or
pcs resource update mb-web statusurl="https://vip.fqdn.ltd/server-status"
```

I followed the setup from: [ClusterLabs.org](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/2.0/html-single/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html)

Within my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/status.conf` file I have:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
     Require local
</Location>
```

There are no redirects to `https` from `http` as I could access both `80` and `443` on the normal domain, when the server was running (before I restarted it last).

I can't even `wget` to see what's happening as the service won't start through the cluster, but if I run `systemctl start httpd` everything runs and `wget http://localhost/server-status` returns:

```
[root@node01 ~]# wget http://localhost/server-status
--2020-05-18 12:58:53--  http://localhost/server-status
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

while `wget https://localhost/server-status` returns:

```
[root@node01 ~]# wget https://localhost/server-status
--2020-05-18 12:58:45--  https://localhost/server-status
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Are there any resources I am missing or not looking, or is there something I have forgotten to activate?

Comment: Do you have `mod_status_module` module in apache config?